# \1 not defined in the RE?

Tags: sed

My code goes like this:

```
cat file.ign | sed 's/^([^A-Za-z0-9]+ )/<ignore>\1<\/ignore>/g'
```

Yet I receive an error saying :

```
sed: 1: "s/^([^A-Za-z0-9]+ )/<ig ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

Answer (score 7):

Parentheses are literal in basic regular expression (BRE) syntax - to make them denote a capture group, they must be escaped, as `\(` and `\)`

Additionally, as noted in a comment by @BenjaminW, `+` is also literal in BRE. GNU sed supports `\+` as a quantifier in BRE:

```
sed 's/^\([^A-Za-z0-9]\+ \)/<ignore>\1<\/ignore>/g'
```

(but other implementations might not). Alternatively, turn on extended regular expression (ERE) mode using the `-E` or `-r` command line switch as appropriate (check your version's documentation):

```
sed -E 's/^([^A-Za-z0-9]+ )/<ignore>\1<\/ignore>/g'
```

or use the POSIX-compliant quantifier `\{1,\}`

```
sed 's/^\([^A-Za-z0-9]\{1,\} \)/<ignore>\1<\/ignore>/g'
```

*ASIDE the `g` (global replacement) modifier won't have any effect here, since `^` anchors the expression to the start of the pattern (which can occur only once per line)*

Comment: Furthermore, `+` is only avalable in ERE; GNU sed supports it as an extension in BRE, but is has to be escaped.

Comment: @BenjaminW. oops yes that's a good point - I missed that

Comment: The `-E` also is GNU or FreeBSD sed, not in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).  If you're going to recommend a non-POSIX solution, mentioning that might help the reader.

Comment: `sed 's#^[^A-Za-z0-9][^A-Za-z0-9]* #<ignore>&</ignore>#'` will do the same in any `sed`, and it's hardly uglier than `\(..\{1,\}..\)/..<\/../` ;-)

Comment: @ThomasDickey But it looks like it has [been accepted](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528) - not sure when it'll make it into the standard, though.

Comment: Perhaps - but the **published** standard is what most people rely on.

Answer (score 2):

Using [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), you can invoke as `sed -E` or else you can escape the parentheses in order to get the back-reference working, but if you're not using GNU sed, you can't rely on back references; [POSIX sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doesn't ([yet](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528)) support the `-E` or `-r` argument for Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) nor does it support GNU's Basic Regular Expression (BRE) backslash notation. (Here's [more on POSIX ERE & BRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), though it doesn't speak in much depth about GNU's BRE implementation allowing escaping into ERE functionality.)

Fortunately, (in this case) you don't need ERE. This should work for you:

```bash
sed 's/^[^A-Za-z0-9][^A-Za-z0-9]* /<ignore>&<\/ignore>/' file.ign
```

BRE doesn't support the `+` quantifier, so I needed to double the nonword character set so it would be "one or more" by requiring "one" and then "zero or more" of them. The ampersand (`&`) denotes the entire match. There's no need to have parentheses around everything in this case. (The beginning-of-line anchor `^` is zero-width and doesn't matter here.)

I removed the `cat` because it's unnecessary. I also removed your `/g` modifier because the `^` anchor means this can only match once per line, so you'll never get a second match and therefore a global replacement doesn't do anything.